# Adding @media Rule by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am adding a  dynamically created image using JavaScript, but I need to remove this object when the viewport is 600px or wider.

Here is what I've tried:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
// (imagine here all the others fields being defined).
img.style='My @media Rule here';
```

However, it did not work. Is it possible doing this by the way I am trying to do?

Comment: Why not add a class to the img you create (img.className = "...";) and use a regular CSS media query targeting that class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create CSS class and apply it when image is dynamically added:

JavaScript:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.className = "imageClass";
img.src = "image/src/image.jpg";
```

And stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .imageClass {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/1/